# Not able to access Amazon S3 object using 'referer'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am trying to set up CloudFront for serving S3 assets but want to take it one step at a time ( the ultimate goal is using signed URLs but we will get there later ).

I have set up an S3 bucket default out the box that is private. And uploaded a file to it (think for demo purposed it is an MP4) - I try and go the the URL and permission denied - brilliant that's what I'd expect.

I thought I would add a policy to the bucket to allow access to the mp4 file from a specific domain and found the below snippet and added it and tailored it to the relevant domain and the correct bucket:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"HTTP referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow only GET requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I put a simple HTML page on the the server with a video tag and put the src to the S3 URL and I still get permission denied.

I have done nothing around IAM as at no point has AWS pointed that out I followed a video from AWS to build CloudFront distribution and an S3 bucket - for now I just want to get an asset rendering from a specified domain name using the S3 URL. Once I have done this I can then look at the next step.

Hope someone can steer me in the right direction - sure it simple but find AWS overwhelming.

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that your HTML file is publicly readable and hosted at www.example.com (or whatever that domain is in real life)? And that you've verified that your browser is sending the correct referer header when you request the MP4 from S3 by clicking a link on the HTML page?

Comment: Did you turn off Block S3 Public Access before adding the Bucket Policy? Also, if you temporarily remove the `Condition`, does it work?

Comment: Please note that `Referer` is easily faked. It is not a good method of adding security to private data.